# How to remove a wall bracket for retail shelving?

Tags: shelving, brackets

This is a support bracket for a retail shelf.  It's super tight and I am unable to remove.  Most just lift up and remove that way, this one won't lift up. How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need a good size pry bar to lift that bracket up off of the vertical standard. We used to put them together and generally used a hammer to install, so some force will be needed.

Comment: Check for any screws/bolts holding it.  Might just need more power, make use of a lever, if painted/bent.

Comment: I'd be tempted to close this as off-topic because it's retail shelving, but I've got some installed in my garage.

Comment: Many Q's posed by electricians about their commercial work have been closed, @Mazura. Not my sole decision to make, not by a long shot. Also, note, I said "tempted", I didn't VtC. And, if I had, you could have hit the review queue and voted to leave it open. That's how it works in this community, if you don't recall. #takeittometa

Answer (score 1):

Raise the entire shelf assembly up off the floor and place a block under the part you want to remove. Now hammer downward on some other part of the shelf - either the corner post itself, or another support bracket. The effect is the same as hammering upward on the one that's too close to the floor to hammer directly.

Answer (score 1):

Some brackets, whether designed for retail or home use, can get well wedged in place and need a good whack with a hammer to break them loose. This looks more like a "foot" than a shelf support/bracket, though. I'd imagine that it looks different than all the other support pieces that you've removed so far.

Since it appears to be a foot to keep the unit upright, it *might* be screwed/bolted in place. Look for any sign of screws anywhere and remove those - this will probably come right out then.

If you can't find any sign of screws/bolts, then:

- If you're disassembling the entire unit, remove all the other brackets from the upright, lay the upright on the floor, hold a block of wood against the bottom of the bracket to protect it, and whack the wood until the bracket comes out. You may need an assistant to stand on the upright to keep it from moving, or brace the upright against the wall.
- If you're leaving the unit in place and just need to remove this bottom brace, slip a pry bar under the brace right next to the upright and pry. You may need to pry a bit from each side to get it to come loose. Use caution, as you pry, you may be leaning over the bracket, and if it comes loose suddenly, you may lose your balance and fall over and/or the bracket could fly loose and hit you.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom foot/bracket on retail shelving shifts & tilts **down** to release - otherwise there'd be nothing holding up an entire free-standing aisle of shelving.

All other shelves tilt up to release [or some are a 'flat lift' but still upwards], as they support weight from on top. The base has to support weight from 'below' - maintaining the balance & stability of the structure.

You release it by lifting the rear uprights & tapping the bracket downward. It may take as much as 8 - 10" of play to release. They're not made to be easy to accidentally remove.

We used to cut them out with an angle-grinder unless the whole structure was coming down. It's quicker.

In normal assembly/disassembly, they're the first part to go on, & the last part to come off. Removing them in situ is difficult, hence our angle grinder approach.

<sup>That stuff looks so much like the old Toys Я Us shelving, it's spooky. I lived with that stuff for 15 years, til they went bust… brrr…</sup>

Comment: @Mazura - I've found a video of some similar type being assembled. They start upside down, but the required assembly/disassembly action becomes obvious. You see him tilt it in then hammer it down from about 16 seconds in - https://player.vimeo.com/video/103005711?autoplay=1 It's not quite the same as the ones we used to work with. They were much bigger & needed more tilt & less hammer.

Comment: Oooohhhh... good point! I just disassembled some I picked up at a store that was closing, and don't remember them doing that, though...